# How to modify this regex to exclude punctuation in a URL?

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching

I've modified a regex that I found [here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) so that it would accept various UK and second-level TLDs.

```
/\b((?:^https?:\/\/|^[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4})(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!@()\[\]{};:'".,<>?]))/i
```

However as you can see in my test data [here](http://rubular.com/r/3KgVUrL1iz), the regex matches URLs such as `www.zapple.@com` and `https://m!crosoft.com` which are not valid.

For some reason `@` symbols are excluded before the `.com` but after the `.` they are not.

Exclamation marks are not excluded at all which is confusing since, as far as I can see, only letters, numbers and dashes are allowed before the period.

Comment: I understand regex pretty well, but that regex is quite hideous ;)  Why don't you just use `URI` (or `Addressable::URI`) to parse the URL, then split the host on "."? `URI.parse(str).host.split(".")`

Comment: Wow, um... I wouldn't want my name on that bit of obsfuscation.  I'd break up the task. First tokenize it. Then validate the preamble. Then validate the domain. etc..

Comment: I just kept hacking away at it until it matched what I wanted. I have no experience with regex so I've decided to go with the `URI::regexp(%w(http https))` method. Less user friendly but a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @ is matched by

```
[^\s()<>]+
```

And the ! mark by

```
(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+
```

I don't know but that doesn't look like a good regex to match url's

Try the following which matches a url according to RFC 3986
Both absolute and relative url'sare supported.

Set case insensitivity to true

```
^
(# Scheme
 [a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*:
 (# Authority & path
  //
  ([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=]+@)?              # User
  ([a-z0-9\-._~%]+                            # Named host
  |\[[a-f0-9:.]+\]                            # IPv6 host
  |\[v[a-f0-9][a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:]+\])  # IPvFuture host
  (:[0-9]+)?                                  # Port
  (/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?          # Path
 |# Path without authority
  (/?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?)?
 )
|# Relative URL (no scheme or authority)
 ([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?  # Relative path
 |(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+/?)                            # Absolute path
)
# Query
(\?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?
# Fragment
(\#[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?
$
```

**Update 1**

This does not match m!crosoft.com and @pple.com It's probably due to someting with Rublar.

[image]

Comment: This is still matching `m!crosoft.com` and `@pple.com` according to Rublar. It also matches `hxxp://www.g00gle.com`.

Comment: It does *not* match m!crosoft.com and @pple.com I updated my answer with the matches.

Comment: As you say it must be a Rublar error. What program is that out of interest?